# Overloading async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have this scenario in a library I'm working on:

I have a couple of asynchronous methods that should work both on a single item and a list of items. The list version would look something like this:

```
public Task<List<Result>> ReadAsync(List<ObjectId> objectIds)
{
  ...
}
```

What would the recommended approach be to write the version of ReadAsync that works on a single item?

```
public Task<Result> ReadAsync(ObjectId objectId)
{
   List<ObjectId> objectIds = new List<ObjectId> { objectId };
   var result = ReadAsync(objectIds); 
   return ?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the list-based version to be the "standard", you would implement it like this:

```
public async Task<Result> ReadAsync(ObjectId objectId)
{
  List<ObjectId> objectIds = new List<ObjectId> { objectId };
  var results = await ReadAsync(objectIds); 
  return results[0];
}
```

If you can let the instance-based version be "standard", and are willing to return an array instead of `List`, then you can do this:

```
public Task<Result[]> ReadAsync(IEnumerable<ObjectId> objectIds)
{
  return Task.WhenAll(objectIds.Select(id => ReadAsync(id)));
}
```